# Is it possible to implement NFC payment in React Native?

Tags: react-native, nfc, payment

As I understand, even if it is possible, it'll only work for android because apple had blocked their NFC chips for 3'rd party apps which don't use Apple Pay.
I tried to use this package: https:[www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nfc-manager](http://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nfc-manager)
However, It seems to work only with simple NFC tags,but not with EMV (Credit Card).
My question is Am I missing something? Or it cannot be done in React Native and I should move to Android Studio instead?
Thanks!

Comment: im looking for the same, if you find a lib or work around please share it.